# Node. Можно ли изменить handshake процесс у tls сервера

Tags: node.js, tls

Ситуация такова, что у имеется tls сервер, написанный на node, и множество клиентов каждый со своим сертификатом. При этом по ходу работы какие-то клиенты могут быть отключены от сервера и их сертификаты убираются из списка доверенных. Ссылка на сертификаты для клиентов хранятся в бд.
Сейчас сервер просто опрашивает базу с некоторой периодичностью на предмет изменения таблицы с клиентами, и в случае изменений создается новый контекст, перезаписывающий доверенные сертификаты.
Имеется ли возможность как-то переписать процедуру проверки сертификатов, чтобы сразу делать запрос в бд, при подключении клиента?

Comment: Начните с описания того как выглядит ваш tls сервер... Вы где-то в коде обрабатываете событие secureConnection - или как-то обошлись без него?

Comment: При создании сервера в tls.createServer передал обработчик. 
В нем проверяю авторизовано ли соединение, если нет кидаю ошибку.
Если авторизовано, то извлекаю данные из бд и начинаю их обработку.
Мне собственно нужно, как-то перехватить событие авторизации клиента.

Comment: А зачем вам это событие? Почему бы не вставить эту самую вашу проверку просто в начало обработчика?

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что сейчас у сервера стоят rejectUnauthorized и requestCert.
Так что если я правильно понимаю, то до этой проверки в connection дело вообще дойти не должно, если сертификат не верен( код достался от старого разрабротчика и сейчас переписывается).
Мне бы как раз и хотелось бы, чтобы с одной стороны сертификаты хранились в базе, с другой чтобы клиент с неправильным сертификатом даже не мог установить соединение.